# Mongo: Error converting JSON to BSON

Tags: c, mongodb, gcc, mongo-c-driver

I am attempting to convert the following MongoDB JSON command into valid BSON using the Mongo C driver:

```
db.test.update({
   "_id" : ObjectId("5624200d4bacd3940b8b2d62"),
  "folders.folder_id": "3_root",
  "folders.files": { $elemMatch: { "file": "5BD252AD-10C9-4DCE-A59C-5E3223BDDC60"}} },
  {$inc : { "folders.0.files.$.favorites.0.like": 1} }
);
```

I have attempted to create it using:

```
query = BCON_NEW ("_id", BCON_OID(&oid));
BSON_APPEND_UTF8 (query, "folders.folder_id", folderPositionRaw);
BSON_APPEND_UTF8 (query, "folders.files", "{" , "$elemMatch","{","file","5BD252AD-10C9-4DCE-A59C-5E3223BDDC60","}","}");

update = BCON_NEW ("$inc", 
    "{", 
    "folders.0.files.$.favorites.0.like", 1,
    "}");
mongoc_collection_update (collection, MONGOC_UPDATE_NONE, query, update, NULL, &error);
```

But it is *way* wrong.

When I compile I get:

> /current/set_fav.c: In function ‘main’:
>   /current/set_fav.c:102: warning: initialization discards qualifiers from pointer target type
>   /current/set_fav.c:168:122: error: macro "BSON_APPEND_UTF8" passed 9 arguments, but takes just 3
>   /current/set_fav.c:168: error: ‘BSON_APPEND_UTF8’ undeclared (first use in this function)
>   /current/set_fav.c:168: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
>   /current/set_fav.c:168: error: for each function it appears in.)

FYI: `folderPositionRaw` has the value of `3_root` set higher up in the codes.

---

To add a little more information: Originally I had the wrong Mongo syntax, but C was happy. I was using the following:

```
query = bson_new ();
bson_oid_init_from_string (&oid, tribe_id);
query = BCON_NEW ("_id", BCON_OID(&oid));       
BSON_APPEND_UTF8 (query, "folders.folder_id", folderPositionRaw);
BSON_APPEND_UTF8 (query, "folders.folder_id.$.files.file", file);
```

I received help from my DB team giving me the correct Mongo syntax (top of post) and in my attempt to structure that into the C BSON I did something wrong.

---

Some progress:

I have updated my codes and they NO longer crash which is a good sign, but the output JSON that is sent to Mongo is not fully structured correctly.  I think the issue is the value 1 that is sent in the mongo $inc command is being sent as a scalar 1 not an int 1.  I have tried both with and without quotes around the 1.  With quotes the code runs, but does not preform the update (no errors returned).  If I remove the quotes the app crashes.

```
query = bson_new ();
bson_oid_init_from_string (&oid, tribe_id);

query = BCON_NEW ("_id", BCON_OID(&oid), "folders.folder_id", folderPositionRaw,"folders.files", 
    "{",
        "$elemMatch",
            "{",
                "file", file,
            "}",
    "}");       

// Find the document
cursor = mongoc_collection_find (collection, MONGOC_QUERY_NONE, 0, 0, 0, query, NULL, NULL);

// update document
update = BCON_NEW ("$inc", 
    "{", 
        "folders.0.files.$.favorites.0.like","1",
    "}");

    str = bson_as_json (update, NULL);
    printf ("***-> %s <-***\n\n",str);

mongoc_collection_update (collection, MONGOC_UPDATE_NONE, query, update, NULL, &error);
```

Comment: Have you included the header that declares `BSON_APPEND_UTF8`?

Comment: Biffen, yes sorry I didn't explain that part.  If I remove the second `BSON_APPEND_UTF8 ` line everything works.  So it is something with that line in how I structured things.

Comment: It looks like the compiler thinks the first occurrence is a *declaration*, and that the second has a different number of arguments, which would suggest a missing *actual* declaration. Could you show us something closer to a [MCVE]?

Comment: biffen - I added more info.  But in general you can string together as many `BSON_APPEND_UTF8` as you like to build the syntax you need.

Comment: Do you have any documentation for `BSON_APPEND_UTF8`? How many arguments does it take? Unless it's a variadic function, one of your lines is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue!

You cannot use a standard `int` it must be a BCON_INT

```
update = BCON_NEW ("$inc", 
    "{", 
        "folders.0.files.$.favorites.0.like",BCON_INT32 (1),
    "}");
```

:)